# Servlet code forward to same page during different scenario instead of another page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

As per my requirement main page contains TextField and radio button.

**Scenario 1:** when the user enter "locationno" in TextField and submit servlet will call DB and fetch  records for entered locationno from Database and forward to locationDetails page.its working fine

**Scenario 2:** when the user enter enters locationno in TextField simultaneously click radio button servlet will call DB and fetch all details for the particular locationno and forward to locationAllDetails page.Here it is fetching records proper but it always forward to locationDetails page instead of locationAllDetails page.
When I click submit button after enter TextField and radio button in the log it shows Outputtype(radio button name) as "ALL" but still it always forward to  locationDetails page instead of locationAllDetails page

what's wrong in the below code my doubt is due to this line

```
 request.setAttribute("locationbean", locResultsList);
```

Please find the code below and help on this.

```
          if (strSearchType != null && strSearchType.equals("locationNo")){
            inLoop = "siteID : ";
            RequestDispatcher rd = null;
            String locationNo = null;

            String flow = null;
            String pagePosition = null;
            String sitePagePositon = null;
            String outputType = null;

            List locResultsList = null;



            try{
                pagePosition = request.getParameter("pagePosition");

                if(pagePosition != null){
                    request.setAttribute("pagePosition",pagePosition);
                    rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/locationDetails.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
else{                                   
                    flow = "locationSearchFlow";
                    locationNo = request.getParameter("locationNo");
                    session.setAttribute("locationNo",locationNo);
                    outputType = request.getParameter("outputType");

                    rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/SiteSearchResults.jsp");

                    LocationCodeDAOBean locDaoBean = new LocationCodeDAOBean();

           List locResultsList = locDaoBean.getLocationResults(locationNo); 

         request.setAttribute("locationbean", locResultsList);

     if(locResultsList.size() == 0){
                            rd =     this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/ExceptionPage.jsp");
                        request.setAttribute("errorMessage","No Records Returned for Site Item Location Details, Req Number = "+siteID);
                        rd.forward(request, response);
                    }else if(outputType.equals("ALL")){

                        locationNo = request.getParameter("locationNo ");
                        session.setAttribute("locationNo ",locationNo );                        

                        LocationCodeDAOBean locDaoALLBean = new LocationCodeDAOBean();
   List locAllResultsList = locDaoALLBean .getALLLocationResults(locationNo);

   request.setAttribute("pagePosition", "0");
                        request.setAttribute("locationALLbean",    locAllResultsList);
                        session.setAttribute("flow",flow);
                        rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/LocationSearchAllResults.jsp");
                        rd.forward(request, response);
      }

                    else{
                        rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/ExceptionPage.jsp");
                        request.setAttribute("errorMessage","No Records Returned for Site Item Location Details, Req Number = "+siteID);
                        rd.forward(request, response);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

After every `forward` do a return.

```
if (pagePosition != null) {
    request.setAttribute("pagePosition", pagePosition);
    rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/locationDetails.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

Comment: If I was the one to ask this question, I would have immediately accepted this answer

Comment: after add return statement now locationAllresults page are working but locationDetails page not working

Comment: Must it maybe written with a capital L: `"/jsp/LocationDetails.jsp"` as the other jsps are capitalized? Check whether it can invoke a simple HTML like jsp.